# JSON object from ASP.NET controller to view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a situation where a when a web page is accessed a controller action runs which retrieves the data for that page based on a user selection.  I am attempting to send the data back to the page as a JSON object, however, the data opens up as one large string in an HTML page.  The controller action, in a nutshell, looks like the following snippet:

```
Public JsonResult MyMethod(string userSelection)
{

    string userData = (string) Data;
    return Json(userData, “text”, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I first tried to use the JQuery `$.getJson()` method but I think this is wrong as I believe it issues another call to the action method for the data, which is not what I want to do.  What I want is to access the JSON object in JavaScript code so I can use the property data to populate fields on the web page.  The basic question is what must I do in my JavaScript to receive the JSON object when the page is first rendered?  I apologize if I am missing something fundamental; this is my first try.

Comment: Please post the requested URL.

Answer (score 1):

I still had no luck today but when I left work I came up with a strategy walking to my car.  A user makes a selection from a page that presents a list prior to entering the page on which I cannot figure out how to work with JsonResult.  Part of the problem is the user selection contains a link that calls the controller/action that returns the JsonResult which conflicts with using $.getJson() within the page where I want to work with JsonResult.  So here is my strategy:  When the user makes the selection that brings them to the (problematic) page, I will call a controller/action that strictly works with (ASP) ViewData, and use the ViewData to initially present that page.  Once on the page, the user can change the selection -- I will handle this with a JavaScript event that uses a $.getJason() call to a different controller/action method that works with (ASP) JsonResult.  After I try this strategy I shall post my results for whomever is interested.

Answer (score 0):

You want `parseJSON` not `getJSON`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Edit - Oh wait you are pointing your browser at the `JsonResult` as if it was an `ActionResult`? That is not going to work.

Render a proper view, and use `getJSON` to call the `JsonResult` action.

Comment: To return JSON from action, JSONResult will work same as ActionResult. JSonResult is inherited from ActionResult.

Comment: @Shyju Right, I think, but am not sure, the OP is saying his route is pointed at the JsonResult action, explaining the json string all over the page.

Comment: I think it is a problem somewhere in  how he handle the data at client side.

Comment: @Shyju That's possible too. We need to see the route url to eliminate it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

`getJSON` is [what](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) you are looking for. Call that on the DOM ready event which will executes once the DOM finishes loading.

```
$(function(){
 //This code will be executed on the DOM ready ( when the page is loaded)

  $.getJSON("YourControllerName/MyMethod?userSelection=someValue",function(data){

      alert(data.FirstName);     
      alert(data.AnotherPropertyName);    

   });
});
```

`getJSON` is a shorthand of jQuery `ajax` method with datatype set as `json`

Assuming your JSON data you are retuning is something like this

```
{
    "FirstName": "Scott",
    "AnotherPropertyName": "SomeValue"
}
```

To return data like above, change your Action method like this

```
public JsonResult MyMethod(string userSelection)
{
  var result=new { FirstName="Scott", AnotherPropertyName="Great"};
  return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You are using a `Json` overload I am unfamiliar with, the only overload I see that accepts a string as the second parameter sets the response MIME type... ?

Comment: @asawyer :Ah ! I copied a wrong thing from clipboard. Thanks for pointing. Corrected it.